# Best practise to navigation in windows phone 8.1[RT] xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, frame

Hello I am working with windows phone 8.1[RT] application , I simply navigate page only . but I found new option we can use `Frame` in xaml also like this

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="White">

    </Border>
    <Button Content="next" Click="Button_Click" Background="Black" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">

        <Frame x:Name="Page1Frame" Background="Black" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Margin="5" />

                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Margin="5" />
                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Margin="5" />
                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Red" Margin="5" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

and navigate this frame like this

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Page1Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
}
```

in this example my 120 height grid remain same and just navigate the frame .
I just want to know which is best practice to use ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Page is page, Frame is frame, they are different.

Suppose your current page named MainPage, if you want to stay in MainPage and change the content of grid in root grid's row 1, you should use:

```
 Page1Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

If you want to leave MainPage to go to another page, you should use:

```
var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; 
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

and in this case, what you see is a blank page without 120 height grid remain.